# Error when trying to format line spacing using variable instead of "Selection"

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

I want to change the line spacing to single and space before and space after = 0 only for the text that has font.size=12 and font.name = "Arial". I recorded I macro  and for all times when the macro recorded `Selection` I replaced in code with `wdDoc.Range` but I´m getting error with the code below in lines `.Replacement.ParagraphFormat` that says `Compile error: Invalid use of property`

How could fix this?

```
Sub SingleLineSpacing()
Dim wdDoc As Document

Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument

    With wdDoc.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Replacement.ParagraphFormat
        .Replacement.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
        .Replacement.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBeforeAuto = False
        .Replacement.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        .Replacement.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfterAuto = False
        .Replacement.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
        .Replacement.ParagraphFormat.LineUnitBefore = 0
        .Replacement.ParagraphFormat.LineUnitAfter = 0
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did it work when it had Selection there?

Comment: @Ger Cas the line '.Replacement.ParagraphFormat' does nothing.  It is merely selecting the object to use.  You can delete it.

Comment: @Freeflow Excellent. I removed that line and now it works. Thanks so much for the help.